# ReadExisting() Method Returns Un-Parseable String?

Tags: string, serial-port, double, c++-cli, typeconverter

So, I have a serial port control (System::IO::Ports::SerialPort) in a c++ win forms app that reads data from the serial connection, as the title might imply. Though, for whatever reason, Microsoft decided that reading data would only return String values, which is ok if you simply parse the string after the fact. Except, when I try to parse the string that is returned from the ReadExisting() command, I get a System.FormatException.

I'm certain that it has something to do with the way that ReadExisting() returns the string value, because when I changed it to ReadLine() I could easily call Double::Parse(string) on it and get a clean return value. Except I don't have the luxury of using ReadLine() because it's too slow for my application. I'm attempting to read every piece of data that comes through that serial connection at 640 Hz, thus when I try to use ReadLine(), waiting for the new line character slows it down by a factor of roughly 10, meaning I'm reading at roughly 64 Hz instead. No data is being lost, but it's just too slow for my application.

Here's the method that is attached the DataReceived event. I'm looking for a way that allows me to parse the string passed back from ReadExisting(). Either that, or a more efficient method for reading that let's me not lose any speed but still allows me to parse the data ultimately so I can work with it.

```
private: System::Void serialPort1_DataReceived(System::Object^  sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e) {
    if (!this->reading) return;
    else 
    {
        try
        {
            //get incoming port and read
            SerialPort^ sp = (SerialPort^)sender;
            String^ sInData = sp->ReadExisting();
            //parse read data
            double inData = Double::Parse(sInData);

            //write data to debugger for testing
            Debug::WriteLine(sInData);

            //start populating the "in" array
            AppendIn(inData);
        }
        catch (Exception^ e)
        {
            Debug::WriteLine(e->Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the message in the `FormatException` says something about the an invalid string. `ReadExisting` reads whatever bytes are available, decodes the bytes to characters, and returns them as a string. Since you're not checking the result of `ReadExisting`, it also might be that there's multiple doubles in there. Since you said that `ReadLine` works, perhaps the string returned from `ReadExisting` is "123\n456\n", and `Double::Parse` is throwing `FormatException` because that's not a valid double.

What I would do is separate the concerns of reading serial bytes vs. parsing the incoming data. Have a buffer of received bytes, and append to it in the `DataReceived` event. When you do that, check if the buffer has enough data, and if so, handle the complete incoming packet, and remove that packet from the buffer. As it is now, you're relying on `ReadLine` to packetize things for you, or you're relying on `DataReceived` to be called once per packet, which it won't be.

Also, I don't understand what you mean about your read speed.

> I'm attempting to read every piece of data ... at **640 Hz**, ... I'm reading at roughly **64 Hz** instead. **No data is being lost**...

If data is coming in 10x faster than you're reading it, there's only two possible choices: Either you're dropping data, or your program is falling further and further behind.

Comment: Oh, you're entirely right about the ReadExisting reading something like "123\n456\n789..." I tossed in a quick debug line that just prints a test string every time the function is called and lo-and-behold the event is being called more along the lines of once for every ~100 bytes of data. As far as speed, I meant that the serial sender is only sending an ascending count from 0-640 for now so that I knew if data was being dropped. Thus, when every number printed, I was puzzled, but it makes sense if there are multiple lines per read as you said. Thanks a ton